# Grid on second tab doesnot load data on render

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a form panel and i have added a tabpanel to it. Tab Panel has 2 tabs. When the form panel is loaded the first tab's grid loads fine but when i click on the second tab i do see the grids but data is not loaded by default. But it does refresh with data When i click on the grid header.

Below is the piece of code that i use to load the grids from controllers.

```
var store = this.getDeficiencyDeficiencyStoreStore();
store.on('load',function() {
    var accountDeliverySettingsGrid = Ext.getCmp('accountDeliverySettingsGrid');
    accountDeliverySettingsGrid.reconfigure(model.allQuartesListStore);
    accountDeliverySettingsGrid.getView().refresh();
})
```

Any help/suggestions/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. I had to use event: activate to explicitly invoke refresh method to get the grids loaded. Below is the piece of code.

```
  listeners: { activate: function(tab)
    { //alert("Put Your Logic Here"); 
    Ext.getCmp('accountDeliverySettingsGrid').getView().refresh(); 
    Ext.getCmp('compositeRelationship').getView().refresh(); 
}
```